# the object stays in a specific distance between two polygons of another animated object

Tags: maxscript

I have a sphere , and I put an object inside it between two polygons, and the inside object is not in the middle distance between them but it is in a specific ratio of distance between them, which i want to do is keeping the inside object in the same distance ratio when I move or scale the sphere simultaneously?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use two additional point helpers for the faces, with this you can use simple position script to calculate that. Example to show what I'm talking about:

```
(
    delete objects
    local sphere1 = Sphere segments:32 radius:10 pos:[35, 65, 0]
    local sphere2 = Sphere segments:32 radius:20 pos:[20, 5, 15]
    local point01 = Point wirecolor:green
    local point02 = Point wirecolor:green
    local point03 = Point size:5 box:on wirecolor:red

    point01.position.controller = Attachment node:sphere1 align:false
    point02.position.controller = Attachment node:sphere2 align:false

    local face1 = AttachCtrl.addNewKey point01.position.controller 0
    local face2 = AttachCtrl.addNewKey point02.position.controller 0

    face1.face = 440
    face1.coord = [0.5, 0]

    face2.face = 540
    face2.coord = [0.5, 0]

    local ctrl = Position_Script()
    ctrl.addObject #point01 point01
    ctrl.addObject #point02 point02
    ctrl.script = "point01.position + 0.8 * (point02.position - point01.position)"
    point03.position.controller = ctrl
)
```

Comment: thank you my friend for the answer,
but i want this operation specifically inside one object.
for example , box001 inside sphere001 between two specific polygons at the specific distance ratio and not in the middle.
and when we change the scale or position of the sphere001 , the box001  is keep its  distance ratio between the polygons simultaneously.

Comment: The solution still applies, only instead of attaching helpers to faces of two different objects use two faces of one object.

Comment: Plus the ratio is there, I don't know from what you'd deduce it would keep the object in the middle when it's 0.8 of the distance of the two faces.

Answer (score 0):

thanks my friend, I have this idea and it is executed perfectly:

```
fn obb obj nod r t=
```

(
    global x1p=nod.pos
    global v1p=polyOp.getFaceCenter obj r
    global v2p=polyOp.getFaceCenter obj t
)
fn obbnew obj nod r2 t2 s1 s2 s3=
(
    global v1p2=polyOp.getFaceCenter obj r2
    global v2p2=polyOp.getFaceCenter obj t2
    global c1=(s2+s3)/2
    global c2=(v1p2+v2p2)/2
    global cn=c2-c1
    nod.pos=s1+cn

)

rollout getset "Alaa Biped" width:285 height:325
(
    button btn1 "old pos bone" pos:[22,16] width:126 height:34
    button btn2 "new pos" pos:[24,88] width:126 height:34
    label lbl1 "" pos:[66,58] width:36 height:21
    label lbl2 "" pos:[67,133] width:36 height:21
    on btn1 pressed do
    (
        ---lCollar
        obb $character $PtlCollar 8958 9498
        global x1=x1p
        global y1=v1p
        global z1=v2p
        lbl1.caption="ok"
    )
    on btn2 pressed do
    (
        obbnew $character $PtlCollar 8958 9498 x1 y1 z1
        lbl2.caption="ok"
    )

)
createDialog getset
-- Set pelves pos

-- Change All

-- Import Skin

Comment: $character = the mesh ,     
-----nod = is the helper inside the mesh = $PtlCollar ,
------r and t = are the ID of the faces ,